# How to solve summation of initial root and summation of the roots of a transcendental equation

Tags: equation-solving

I'm stuck to solve this and I really hope someone could help me. My question is a bit lengthy. I want to find the summation of first root and roots of a transcendental equation but I don't know how to ask Mathematica when to substitute the first root and the summation of the roots. Below is what I want to find which is `f_1`.

[image]

```
E0(Lambda_p) = BesselJ[1, Subscript[\[Lambda], p]  k] BesselY[0, 
     Subscript[\[Lambda], p]  Rz] - 
   BesselY[1, Subscript[\[Lambda], p] k] BesselJ[0, 
     Subscript[\[Lambda], p]  Rz];

E03(Lambda_m) = BesselJ[1, Subscript[\[Lambda], m]  k] BesselY[0, 
     Subscript[\[Lambda], m]   Rz] - 
   BesselY[1, Subscript[\[Lambda], m] k] BesselJ[0, 
     Subscript[\[Lambda], m]  Rz];

add = E0/E03;
```

This is the transcendental equation. I managed to get the initial root when I'm changing the parameter `\[CurlyCapitalUpsilon]` as below :

```
\[CurlyCapitalUpsilon] = {0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 
  100}; k = 0.1; Rz = 0.99; Da = 1; \[CapitalOmega] = 0.5;

eqns = Table[
   Subscript[\[Lambda], 
     m]*(BesselY[1, Subscript[\[Lambda], m] k] BesselJ[1, 
         Subscript[\[Lambda], m] Rz] - 
       BesselY[1, Subscript[\[Lambda], m] Rz] BesselJ[1, 
         Subscript[\[Lambda], m] k]) == -(BesselY[0, 
          Subscript[\[Lambda], m] Rz] BesselJ[1, 
          Subscript[\[Lambda], m] k] - 
        BesselY[1, Subscript[\[Lambda], m] k] BesselJ[0, 
          Subscript[\[Lambda], m] Rz]) (\[CurlyCapitalUpsilon][[m]] + 
       Da*\[CapitalOmega]), {m, 1, 5}];

roots = Table[
  FindRoot[eqns[[m]], {Subscript[\[Lambda], m], 1}], {m, 1, 5}]

{{Subscript[\[Lambda], 1] -> 0.96044}, {Subscript[\[Lambda], 2] -> 
   1.03103}, {Subscript[\[Lambda], 3] -> 
   1.47906}, {Subscript[\[Lambda], 4] -> 
   2.24329}, {Subscript[\[Lambda], 5] -> 2.4481}}
```

I tried to solve but I don't know how to ask Mathematica to differentiate when to use first root and summation of the roots. Below is what I tried but did not get the answer

```
find[p_] := 
 Sum[add/(roots[[p, 1, 2]]^2 - roots[[m, 1, 2]]^2), {m, 1, 5}]

lst = Join[{{"\[CurlyCapitalUpsilon]", 
     "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Alpha]\), \(p\)]\)", 
     "\[Sum]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[SubscriptBox[\(\[Alpha]\), \(p\)], \
\(2\)]\)-\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[SubscriptBox[\(\[Alpha]\), \(m\)], \
\(2\)]\)"}}, 
   Table[{\[CurlyCapitalUpsilon][[m]], roots[[m, 1, 2]], find[m]}, {m,
      1, 5}]];

Grid[lst, Dividers -> All]
```

Comment: plz provide the math definition and details of E0 and E03 that make the add
i want to make sure how and why you chosen BesselJ & BesselY !!

Comment: On how and why I chose BesselJ & BesselY is by using the Bessel equation to solve the linear second order DE analytically. E0 and E03 are an equation used to get ADD by dividing EO with EO3. I don't know how to ask Mathematica when to use the initial root and the summation of the root to solve the equation f1.